# Remix-ide: how to set “runs” for optimizer at a value different from the default 200?

Tags: remix

As you may know, the default solc optimizer “runs” value is 200.

Apparently remix does not permit to change this value.

Has someone any idea of how to change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone might have a better idea, but you could serve Remix locally on your own machine by following the instructions for building [here](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide#installation) and [here](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide#developing).

Once you've understood the build flow, you can then tweak the `runs` value in the [`compiler-input.js`](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide/blob/14c22658ef5b6aa49ee31d5c92882c8a3c9e42fe/src/app/compiler/compiler-input.js#L10) file:

```
module.exports = (sources, opts) => {
  return JSON.stringify({
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: sources,
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: opts.optimize === true || opts.optimize === 1,
        runs: 200
      },
....
```

Comment: This is a brilliant idea. It is not applicable in this exact moment because the current version, 0.7.5, suffers from a bug in remixd interface that, for the moment, requires to use the online version. But it is brilliant!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the bug in the current version :-) You could try `git clone`-ing a version from before the bug was introduced, but you'd need to work out which commit introduced the bug. This might, a) be more hassle than it's worth, and b) remove some other functionalities that you need for your testing. Hopefully the bug will be resolved in the near future :-)

Comment: Indeed dev team promised to fix this soon...